# Finding spurious regression based on Ferson et al and by detecting co-integration

Tags: regression, cointegration, spurious-correlation

After reading Ferson et al's (2003) paper on spurious regression, I understand that he uses extensive simulations to generate the true regressors and then compare them with those in the literature to find out those spurious regressors. What I am still confused about is, how spurious regression can be discovered by this approach in this paper since we don't have a pool of regressors all the time?

Is it possible to detect any spurious regression by finding co-integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to detect any spurious regression by finding co-integration?

On the contrary: if cointegration is present, then the estimated *statistical* relationship is genuine and there might be a *causal* relationship between the variables, i.e. the regression might be not spurious.

However, presence of a statistical relationship (such as correlation or cointegration) does not guarantee presence of a causal relationship -- as the cointegrated variables could all be caused by yet another variable (omitted from the regression model) without causing each other.